# Checking database for existing data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to search my database to see if a unique ID is already existing. The database is laid out as so:

[image]

The code I'm using to get to that `voters` spot is:

```
    let ref = firebase.database().ref('players/' + playerId + '/voters');

    ref.orderByChild(uid).equalTo(uid).once("value",snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(child => {
      ref.child(uid).set(1);   
      })
    });
```

playerId in this case is -L434GfPd9IXR8aOLfCR, where-as uid is the vKl6rlUul0WsbeWVORz3twPUfnd2

At some point, there will be a lot of UIDs under the voters child, but currently there is just one. I can't seem to get the path right to search through the voters and check to see if it's present. If it see's the unique ID stored in uid in `voters`, it will set the value to that uid to 1.

I'm also not sure if the snapshot.forEach is relevant here or not

Answer (score 2):

This should be just:

```
let ref = firebase.database().ref('players').child(playerId).child('voters');

ref.child(uid).once('value', snap => {
  if (snap.exists) {
    // a vote has already been recorded
  } else {
    // there is not already a vote there
  }
});
```

Comment: Is the `if (snap.exists)` checking to see if the UID is currently in `voters`? It seems to be saying it exists as soon as I push player content (before there is a UID in `voters`). If I have 20 unique UID's in `voters`, would the `if (snap.exists)` check each for a match and return true upon finding a match?